# how to calculate sum of quantite in an object

Tags: javascript

hello I am trying to obtain the total of the quandites for 77777+88888+99999+the others

I have a piece of code in which I would like to calculate items but with different quantities

so I have for example for articles 77777 ----10 under articles

for item 88888 20 sub items

for item 99999 30 sub items

imagine that the user adds 4 items 77777 to his basket, this must make a total of 40

if he adds 2 items 88888 that makes a total of 40

if he adds 3 items 99999 that makes a total of 90

if he adds 18 more items that makes a total of 18

So the absolute total is 40+40+90+18=188 items

My code is not working correctly at the moment

```
obj.totalpanierpromotion = function() {
    var totalpanierpromotion = 0;
    for(var item in panier) {
        //console.log(panier[item]);
        if (panier[item].nom == 77777) {
            panier[item].quantite = 10 ;
            totalpanierpromotion +=  panier[item].quantite;
        } else if (panier[item].nom == 88888) {
            panier[item].quantite = 20 ;
            totalpanierpromotion +=  panier[item].quantite;
        } else if (panier[item].nom == 99999) {
            panier[item].quantite = 30 ;
            totalpanierpromotion +=  panier[item].quantite;
        }else {
            totalpanierpromotion +=  panier[item].quantite;
        }
    }
    console.log(Number(totalpanierpromotion));
    return Number(totalpanierpromotion);
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you supply a sample data and the wanted output.

Comment: Thank you for the answer
for example 10 items of 77777 +15 items 88888+5 items 99999+40 others=70 items (numbers are examples

Comment: We need to know the desired output so providing a sample of data and the output should help us understand your issue and most likely to provide some helpful answers.

Comment: You need to include the definition of `obj` and `panier`, we shouldn't have to guess. In fact, going through those two values over you'll probably figure it out yourself.

Comment: I changed my request

Comment: @charles could you add the content of `obj` and `panier` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly it's simple

```js
var obj = {}
obj.totalpanierpromotion = function() {
  var totalpanierpromotion = 0;
  for (var item in panier) {
    //console.log(panier[item]);
    if (panier[item].nom == 77777) {
      panier[item].quantite = 10;
      totalpanierpromotion += panier[item].quantite;
    } else if (panier[item].nom == 88888) {
      panier[item].quantite = 20;
      totalpanierpromotion += panier[item].quantite;
    } else if (panier[item].nom == 99999) {
      panier[item].quantite = 30;
      totalpanierpromotion += panier[item].quantite;
    } else {
      panier[item].quantite = 1;
      totalpanierpromotion += panier[item].quantite;
    }
  }
  console.log(Number(totalpanierpromotion));
  return Number(totalpanierpromotion);
}
var panier = {
  "1": {
    nom: 77777
  },
  "2": {
    nom: 77777
  },
  "3": {
    nom: 88888
  },
  "4": {
    nom: 00000
  }  
}

obj.totalpanierpromotion()
console.log(panier)
```